# using sharpsvn client.status in c#

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I've just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446643/using-client-status-in-c-with-sharpsvn), and I have a question about it:
How do I set the client to look at a certain repository? In the example there's a use in the working copy's location, so how can the client know where to check for diffs?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN stores the location of the repository inside the working copy, hence all of those `.svn` directories that appear after the first checkout.